# NHibernate Fetch / ThenFetch for joined siblings

Tags: linq, nhibernate, join, fetch

I have the following (simplified) hierarchy of entities:

```
RootClass
->DescriptorClass
->SomeChild->DescriptorClass
           ->SomeGrandChild
```

I would like to fetch everything in a single query, if possible.

Currently I have the following:

```
Session.Query<RootClass>().Where(/*some expressions here*/)
                    .Fetch(v => v.DescriptorClass)
                    .Fetch(v => v.SomeChild).ThenFetch(v => v.SomeGrandChild)
                    .Fetch(v => v.SomeChild).ThenFetch(v => v.DescriptorClass);
```

it works fine but it creates an SQL query with two joins on SomeChild. Obviously, I have to get rid of that second Fetch(v => v.SomeChild) but I cannot find how to do it. 
I tried:

```
Session.Query<RootClass>().Where(/*some expressions here*/)
                    .Fetch(v => v.DescriptorClass)
                    .Fetch(v => v.SomeChild).ThenFetch(v => v.SomeGrandChild)
                    .ThenFetch(v => v.DescriptorClass); //<- wrong, tries to find DescriptorClass on SomeGranchild
```

and

```
Session.Query<RootClass>().Where(/*some expressions here*/)
                    .Fetch(v => v.DescriptorClass)
                    .Fetch(v => v.SomeChild).ThenFetch(v => v.SomeGrandChild)
                    .Fetch(v => v.DescriptorClass); //<- wrong, loads the same DescriptorClass of RootClass, not on SomeChild
```

How do I tell NHibernate to create a single join on SomeChild and then fetch SomeGrandChild and DescriptorClass of SomeChild?

Answer (score 1):

For this type of query, switch to using the LINQ query syntax instead of lambdas as it gives you more control and typically outputs more efficient and cleaner SQL.

Take a look at the sample below and notice how I am able to reference the Customer entity multiple times by using the alias 'c'.

```
var customers =
    (
        from c in session.Query<Customer>()
        from a in c.Addresses
        from pn in c.PhoneNumbers
        where c.Status == "Active"
                && a.City == "Dallas"
                && pn.AreaCode == "972"
        select c )
        .ToList();
```

This will result in the following SQL using NHibernate:

```
SELECT
    customer0_.CustomerId as Customer1_135_0_,
    customer0_.Status as Customer1_135_1_
FROM
    Customer customer0_
INNER JOIN
    CustomerAddresses customeraddr1_
        ON customer0_.CustomerId=customeraddr1_.CustomerId
INNER JOIN
    CustomerPhoneNumbers customerphon2_
        ON customer0_.CustomerId=customerphon2_.CustomerId
WHERE
    customer0_.Status='Active' /* @p0 */
    AND customeraddr1_.City = 'Dallas' /* @p1 */
    AND customerphon2_.AreaCode = '972' /* @p2 */;
```

Comment: I got: "Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'". Most probably, because "from" is issuing "SelectMany" but I have single SomeChild/DescriptorClass/SomeGrandChild and not collections of them.